# how can I go about creating a dashboard in the post section of wordpress admin

Tags: dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard in post section of wordpress admin area. I want it just underneath the Publish dashboard.

like for example this code here place a dashboard in immediately when I log into the admin area.

```
// Create the function to output the contents of our Dashboard Widget

function example_dashboard_widget_function() {
    // Display whatever it is you want to show
    echo "Hello World, I'm a great Dashboard Widget";
} 

// Create the function use in the action hook

function example_add_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('example_dashboard_widget', 'Example Dashboard Widget', 'example_dashboard_widget_function');   
} 

// Hook into the 'wp_dashboard_setup' action to register our other functions

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'example_add_dashboard_widgets' );
```

Comment: Looks like you are confusing some terms. First you need to know what is *Dashboard*, a *Dashboard Widget* and a *Meta Box*. As mrwweb says, take a look at the Codex. And I suspect that you may be referring to [Custom Meta Boxes](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/), no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into the [`add_menu_page()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and then use the `$position` parameter to place it in the menu where you want it.

Comment: Hey mrwweb, thanks for your answer... can you reference my code above so that I can understand. thank.

Comment: That code is for adding a dashboard widget to the existing Dashboard ( [Codex Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_dashboard_widget) ). You'll need to start with the `$function` parameter for `add_menu_page()` which gives you the callback for outputting your new page's content. It's all there in the Codex, you just have to start reading.